# How to import astyanax client example code in my workspace

Tags: java, cassandra, astyanax

I have recently started working with Cassandra database and I was thinking of using `Netflix client astyanax`. I went into this page-

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax

And I thought after cloning the git repository, I can simply import the maven projects.

**But after cloning the above repository, I cannot find out any pom.xml file in that? Am I looking at some wrong place?** If not, then how should I import all the astyanax client examples into my workspace and play around with that.

Basically, I am just trying to play around with astyanax example and learn how to use astyanax client.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because they are using [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to build their projects.
You should download the tool and check its documentation, it's even simpler than Maven.

There is Gradle for Eclipse - if you are using Eclipse. Or even Springsource Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse. That way you should be able to import the project(s) without any modification.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any maven projects for astyanax cassandra client as well?

Comment: It seems they moved from Maven to Gradle, so no luck there. Check my updated answer. If you're not using Eclipse you can check if there are gradle-to-maven converters.